# Cut and separated object don't fit in real life

Tags: 3d-printing, knife-tool

My problem is with cutting one big irregular pipe in two pieces which are printable in SLA 3d printer. After have it cut with "knife" I merge two edges with "bridge edge loops". The procedure is repeated for the other pieces. The problem occurs after printing them. Two pieces don't fit perfectly with each other. They don't adhere. Its impossible to glue them together.

EDIT:
its 100 per cent problem with mesh in blender. 
the big object is made as a "shell" of other object which had one layer of mesh. It was done in order to get thickness of the wall ( solidify modifier did not work well, he spoils it because of object irregularity). So I did one big sphere and then shrinkwrap modifier and remesh modifier many times over the origin object. Later, the same procedure with second sphere but with offset 2mm (2mm- thickness of the wall).
Then I join this two layers (shrink-wrapped spheres) in one big object. I cut it with knife in perspective view. The bridge edge loops create flat surfaces.

[image: Two edges selected]

[image: bridging edge loops]

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with Blender specifically.

Comment: How do you cut the objects? What did they look like before cutting? Were they fitting each other before they were cut? This indeed can be out of Blender related field

Comment: Had you any unapplied modifier before cutting? did you edit anything after cutting? do the parts match well in 3d before printing? just trying to guess.

Comment: Did you use knife in perspective or orthographic view? And does bridge edgeloops creates a flat surface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender but about 3D printing.